# How to get input's attributes and it's value?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my html and javascript structure and I'm gettin my attributes with parameters it's okey so far

```js
var input  =  document.getElementById("username").attributes;
var ul     =  document.createElement("ul");

for(var i=0; i<input.length;i++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var data = input[i].name + ":" + input[i].value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(data);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">
```

but if I want to get my all input data it's give only first input attributes. for example:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input").attributes;
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var data = input[i].name + ":" + input[i].value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(data);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-id="2" placeholder="Enter your password">
```

and this example gave me a length error if you check it out you will see

So I'm trying to learn pure javascript that's why I won't use in any project  I'm trying to understand its logic

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` return an HTMLCollection (array-like object) that doesn't have a property called `attributes`).

Comment: **Remove the `.attributes` from the first line!**

Comment: thank you @ibrahimmahrir I did it but I wonder that how will I get my all input attributes with value ? I remove but nothing change

Comment: You want to show all the attributes for all the inputs? Or just the `name` and `value` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` is different than `getElementById`. It returns an **array-like** object.

Try: `var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].attributes;`

or `var input = document.querySelector("input").attributes;`

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].attributes;
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var data = input[i].name + ":" + input[i].value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(data);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-id="2" placeholder="Enter your password">
```

If you want to get attributes from every element, just implement a **second loop**.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input[k].attributes.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var data = input[k].attributes[i].name + ":" + input[k].attributes[i].value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(data);
    li.appendChild(text);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-id="2" placeholder="Enter your password">
```

**ES6** solution.

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => {
  Array.from(v.attributes).forEach(c => {
    document.write(`${c.name}: ${c.value}<br>`);
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-id="2" placeholder="Enter your password"><br>
```

Comment: yes thank you but how can I get all input's attributes with value ?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to push attributes for each input in input. And then input will be an array of arrays. So you will need to access each array inside input array using two loops.

```js
var input = [];
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).forEach(function(el){
 input.push(el.attributes);
});
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j<input[i].length; j++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var data = input[i][j].name + ":" + input[i][j].value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(data);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="user" class="form-control" data-id="1" placeholder="type a your username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" data-id="2" placeholder="Enter your password">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input").attributes;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
var this_input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].attributes;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var data = this_input.name + ":" + this_input.value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(data);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```